# IOS UIButton retain cycle

Tags: ios, retain-cycle

I have a button on a VC as a subview of my root view.
The VC is loaded from a storyboard.

I get this very weird retain cycle:

[image]

Can anyone assist?

Comment: Can you post a minimal project that demonstrates the issue?